# Can invoke_signed Be Used in Solana Native Programs to Handle SPL Tokens for Staking?

Tags: spl-token, native-programs, invoke

While reviewing the Solana codebase, I came across the invoke_signed function, which is commonly used for cross-program invocations. I'm particularly interested in understanding if it's possible to utilize invoke_signed within a Solana native program, such as the Stake program.

My goal is to explore the feasibility of implementing staking functionality in a Solana native program while using SPL (Solana Program Library) tokens as the staked assets. In essence, I would like to know if it's possible to call SPL token methods via invoke_signed or any other suitable method within a native program. This would involve the ability to add or subtract SPL tokens from a wallet in a staking context.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or references to relevant code examples or documentation that can shed light on this matter. If invoke_signed is not the appropriate approach for this use case, I would welcome suggestions on alternative methods to achieve the desired functionality within a Solana native program.

Comment: Check this topic, i think it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71730814/transfer-spl-token-using-rust

Answer (score 2):

You can call a CPI to any Solana program, including the Token program which generally manages SPL tokens.

If you look into the source of a CPI call like `token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, amount)`, you'll see that it uses `solana_program::program::invoke_signed` itself under the hood. Here's how the Anchor source calls the native `mint_to ix` from the token program:

```
pub fn mint_to<'info>(
    ctx: CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, MintTo<'info>>,
    amount: u64,
) -> Result<()> {
    let ix = spl_token::instruction::mint_to(
        &spl_token::ID,
        ctx.accounts.mint.key,
        ctx.accounts.to.key,
        ctx.accounts.authority.key,
        &[],
        amount,
    )?;
    solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.to.clone(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.clone(),
            ctx.accounts.authority.clone(),
        ],
        ctx.signer_seeds,
    )
    .map_err(Into::into)
}
```

(https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/src/anchor_spl/token.rs.html#64)

Comment: Thanks, @Whiteseal for your answer. However, I understand the CPI is totally possible in a normal Solana program (Smart contract) but the issue I am facing is using the CPI in native programs, the ones that are shipped with Solana codebase like the Stake and Vote program. 

When using the CPI there, the invoke function requires the AccountInfo, however in native programs we have the BorrowedAccounts.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.

`invoke` - Used when you want to cpi into another program using your keypair(an onCurve address)

`invoke_signed` - used when you want to cpi into another program but you want your pda to sign instead.

Here is a link to `invoke` being used to create a token mint - https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/bbe6a8d8a43302c233bf8ae9017c74e9f73dabea/tokens/nft-minter/native/program/src/instructions/create.rs#L60-L74

Here is a link to `invoke_signed` being used to call mpl to create the metadata account - https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/bbe6a8d8a43302c233bf8ae9017c74e9f73dabea/tokens/pda-mint-authority/native/program/src/instructions/create.rs#L91-L119

invoke and invoke signed docs - https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs

Comment: Thanks, @Jimii for your answer. However, I understand the CPI is totally possible in a normal Solana program (Smart contract) but the issue I am facing is using the CPI in native programs, the ones that are shipped with Solana codebase like the Stake and Vote program. 

When using the CPI there, the invoke function requires the AccountInfo, however in native programs we have the BorrowedAccounts.

Comment: @SyedGhazanferAnwar, I misunderstood you. In that case, check this out https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/account/struct.Account.html#using-account-with-non-anchor-programs. You will need to implement the functions required by the Account yourself and a wrapper type around the structs you'll be working with. 

The docs are great to get started. 

I also haven't worked with `stake` or `vote` programs